# Filter option in a if formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, filter, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have searched every where, but I cannot find an answer to this.

I have a sheet containing information regarding different pipes running under a railway. There are different owners of these pipes (*18 to be exact*) through out the length of the railway.

Here is an example

```
ID    TYPE    INFO1    INFO2    OWNER

 1     A       GAS     STAYS     GC

 2     A       TELE    GOES      TC

 3     B       GAS     GOES      GC

 4     A       POW     STAYS     EC

 ...
```

and so on so forth for 500 pipes.

If I then use a filter option to only show all pipes from one owner, I would like the owners contact information to be inserted in cells `B3:F6`. I have the contact information in another sheet.

Is this possible? If yes, then how do I do it?

Comment: They need to get shorted and printed like this, because the final product should be 18 prints for each owner, so I do need the filter function.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in a helper column with a formula like this:

`=SUBTOTAL(3,A2)`

[Assuming column A is a column that will be populated for every row]

That will show a 1 in visible rows, so you can get the first visible owner with a formula like

`=INDEX(Owner,MATCH(1,Filter,0))`

....and you can use that in lookup/index formulas to retrieve contact info for that owner